# Can an InfoPath 2010 dropdown be populated by a SP List column with multiple choice values?

Tags: list, infopath, multiple-values

I have a list with a column that accepts multiple values (a "choice" type with checkboxes) and wish to display the same available choice options on an InfoPath 2010 form. I'd prefer to accomplish this without code. With a data source to the list, I can populate a dropdown with values but only those that are first in the list of values for any item displays. (e.g. ListItem1=**a**,b,c and ListItem2=**b**,c, then dropdown only displays items for a & b)

Is there a way to display ALL the available values in the comma separated values of each in List item in the form dropdown?

Comment: Why did this receive a downvote? The question is clear and has context and relevance. Please comment if you disagree.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
I believe I answered 2 questions:

- the question in the title:
  "Can an InfoPath 2010 dropdown be populated by a SP List column with multiple choice values?"
  A: impossible in its original formulation
- "I have a list with a column that accepts multiple values (a "choice" type with checkboxes) and wish to display the same available choice options on an InfoPath 2010 form"

  A: I demonstrated that it is being done automatically on creating Infopath form by pressing "Customize button" on ribbon

Further on, the author insists on multiple self-contradicting, incompatible to each another,   incorrect or incomprehensible statements and doubts which I believe **the questioner should post as separate questions** to avoid further mess and lengthy discussion

---

I cannot reproduce what you described in your question

I created **MuChoiceList** list with **MuChoice** field of:

- The type of information in this column is: Choice (menu to choose from)
- Type each choice on a separate line:

  - aaa
  - bbb
  - ccc
- Display choices using:    Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)

[image]

Filled it with data according to your description:

[image]

Created Infopath form and checked that it is impossible to bind a **Drop-Down List Box** control in Infopath form with **MuChoice** field of **MuChoiceList** list using either Main Data Connection or specially additionally created manually, using wizard, **Secondary Data Connetion**/Source. Only with  following Infopath controls:

- Multiple Selection List Box
- Bulleted List
- Numbered List
- Plain List
- Repeated Table
- Repeating Section

If to create Infopath form by pressing **Customize From** button on ribbon, then **Multiple Selection List Box** control is created and bound to **MuChoice** field of **MuChoiceList** automatically (or by default)

[image]

And I have no problems to choose, createe, edit multi-choice selections

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and thorough test of the scenario I described. I would expect the similar multi-selction controls would be available for the **Customize Form** for the column in the given list; but I am interested in limiting the selection to a single item. Also, my form is in another form library and pulling data from the List. Your

Comment: (..continued) Thank you for your prompt and thorough test of the scenario I described. I would expect the similar multi-selction controls would be available for the **Customize Form** for the column in the given list; but I am interested in limiting the selection to a single item. Also, my form is in another form library and pulling data from the List via Data Conntection. In using the multi-choice control on the form, I get a similar behavior as before (only first item of each column and not all items in any column ite, set). [link](http://i47.tinypic.com/2ahfi8p.png)

Comment: I believe I answered 2 of your questions and have difficulties to understand your terminology as well as multiple self-contradicting and incorrect statements of what you have done and failed to have done. Please put one question per post and avoid lengthy discussions, these are the guidelines on SE

Comment: You have provided answers for how an InfoPath form can display the multiple-choice controls using the Customize From button. I apologize for my inconsistent information; I tried to edit my entry but I found I was not able to edit 5 minutes after submitting. Since I've not effectively described my scenario, I may consider submitting a separate question describing the problem I’m observing. Thanks you so much for the serious review of the question and thorough answers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Gennady overlooked it, or if this is a more recent update, but yes, actually it is possible.  I just did it.

In your InfoPath form, open up the Drop-Down List Box Properties for the field you want to populate.  Select "Get choices from an external data source."

Select the data source (ensuring that the Choice field is included in the data connection).

For ENTRIES, you will select all the way down to the "VALUE" level, and set any necessary filter (if you are applying one.  I select "Show only entries with unique display names".

For VALUE and DISPLAY NAME, it will default to "."

And your off to the races.  Best of luck!